# how to create defect in rally for a particular workspace, project and testcase Id using the rest api in java

Tags: java, rest, rally

also can you explain from whrere I can get the testcase ID, project Id, workspace Id, defect owner values. 
I have tried to create a custum HTML to get some values but not the testcase value, defect owner

Answer (score 0):

To set workspace on query request:

```
String workspaceRef = "/workspace/12345";
QueryRequest storyRequest = new QueryRequest("HierarchicalRequirement");
storyRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
```

To set project on query request:

```
String projectRef = "/project/3456";
QueryRequest defectRequest = new QueryRequest("Defect");
defectRequest.setProject(projectRef);
defectRequest.setScopedDown(true);
defectRequest.setScopedUp(false);
```

To set project on create request:

```
String projectRef = "/project/3456";
JsonObject newStory = new JsonObject();
newStory.addProperty("Project", projectRef);
```

Rally artifacts have two types of IDs: ObjectID that is unique across entire Rally stack, and FormattedID, which is unique only within a workspace.

This screenshot shows both. The ObjectID is the string in the URL: 28072723008, and FormattedID is TC1.

[image]

You may always find out ObjectID of any object in Rally in the [WS API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/). Here is a query by username that returns the reference that contains user's ObjectID: 12868523447

[image]